# Datepicker box is not displaying selected date from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datepicker, laravel-blade

[image]

In this image you can see date is showing

[image]

but in 2nd image(Date picker) it shows the today date not the selected date.
my code is below

```
 < input name="period" id="period" type="text" value="{{$item->period}}" class="validate date-picker" >
```

JavaScript code is:

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
```

Thanks in advance 
faisal

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, when [asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it's preferable to share a [complete yet minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows developers to see the issue you're having. In this case it's good to see your HTML and JavaScript, but we also need to know what the result is of `$item->period`, can you use a dump-statement before that line in your view? Like `{{ dd($item->period) }}`?

Comment: Just wondering: why did you rollback the edit @Shree made? The improvements in [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) were right on spot. We format things here at SO because it improves readability.

Comment: I am not going to format it's again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use setDate( date ):
It set the date for the datepicker.

eg:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "yourdate" );
```

Comment: Thank you all.I found my answer with   this piece of code                                                 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "yourdate" );

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the input value format of date wrong that why it is not working

For example, you are setting the value of input field "10-29-2012" and you have specified the format "yyyy-mm-dd" your both format should be same the below is the working sample

The documentation link can be also helpful for you of date picker

[Date picker set date](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdates) `

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#js-date').datepicker({
     format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         With data provide attribute
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data-date">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <p class="bg-info">
            Uses the data-provide attribute in HTML
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         With JavaScript
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-date" value="2018-12-19">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <p class="bg-info">
            No data-provide attribute in HTML. Initialized using JavaScript
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <p class="bg-primary" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            Plugin Used: <a href="https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker">https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker</a>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```